# Submitting the app with Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

First off, I've uploaded the build to AppStore using Xcode 7 beta and only after pressing the "Submit for review" it has shown me the following error:

> Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the
>   public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, and iOS 8 SDK or later.
>   Don't submit apps built with beta software.

So I've updated to recent 7.0.1 version, archived the build, uploaded it to App Store.

And guess what? It shows the same error.

Browsed the forum, tried opening the `plist file` of the archived build, but the  "BuildMachineOSBuild" line already contains "14F27" (that worked for other guys on the forum).

Apple forums are filled with cases of this error and nobody has a clue.

NB: The issue was **solved** by Apple about an hour ago.
They reacted pretty fast.

Comment: Have you changed the build assigned to your development version in iTunes Connect?

Comment: yes, first thing i did. and it took 30 minutes to process, never been that long before @Adam

Comment: Do a clean build with Xcode 7.0.1. The failure to do a clean build first is probably causing the issue.

Comment: @rmaddy i've performed cleaning several times. and archived project plist says the version of Xcode is correct 0701

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug, and you're not alone: See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20467. Since it's Apple's bug, not yours, there's nothing you can do at this point except file a bug report and wait.

**EDIT** The OP now reports that Apple has fixed the bug.

Comment: i've filed the bug. crossed fingers. lets wait and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back - glad that Apple got this sorted!

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not fixed for all.  I have the issue and I'm getting the same error as OP.  I submitted a ticket last night and called this morning as soon as the call center opened.  7 hrs later and I still cannot submit my app for review.

Comment: Still no word from Apple support. I keep trying to submit and I'm getting the same error message.

Comment: Update: Apple Support called me and instructed me to use El Capitan from the App Store and not my Dev Program copy...even though I'd used the exact same OS to submit the prior build.  Oh well... I installed it and everything works fine now.  OS X 10.11 + Xcode 7.0.1, both from the app store now work for submissions.  Apparently now having a Beta or GM operating system is bad for the tool chain for app store submissions  @matt

Comment: @CQH Very interesting. I always wondered whether the GM was _really_ the same as the release version. And this seems to show that it isn't.

Comment: @matt It's crazy. I actually mentioned using "GM" to the rep on the phone and he *specifically* said, "Do not use GM...use the one from the app store."

Comment: I am using El Capitan from the App Store and Xcode 7.0.1. The problem is still happening. One more half-cooked stuff from Apple to developers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change `info.plist` of your application.

1. In XCode `Archives` go to archive's folder (right-click -> `Show in Finder`)
2. Open `Products/Applications/<your app name>` -> `Show package contents`
3. Open `info.plist` in application package with XCode
4. Significant fields is

   - `DTXcode` - `0700` (XCode 7.0)
   - `DTXcodeBuild` - `7A220` (XCode 7.0)
   - `DTXcodeBuild` - `13A344` (iOS 9 SDK)
   - `DTSDKBuild` - `13A344` (iOS 9 SDK)

Optionally, you can change `BuildMachineOSBuild` to `14F27` (Yosemite 10.10.5)

*P.S. In most cases, `Invalid Toolchain` is an iTC bug, that will be fixed sooner or later. This receipt can help you to submit your application, but application itself can become invalid, so, review team can reject it.*

Comment: @DavidRobertson - no it was not.